What is known about sum of divisors of $n$ equal to $kn$ with $k$ not being two?
Let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of positive divisors of $n$. If $\sigma(n)=2n$  we have that $n$ is one of the perfect numbers as $6$, $28$, $496$ and in general $2^{p-1}\cdot(2^p-1)$, where $2^p-1$ is prime.
What is known about the case $\sigma(n)=kn$  with  $k\neq 2$?

This question is too broad. At any rate, there has been a lot of research on these numbers, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply_perfect_number

If $k$ is meant to be real, then for $k \lt 2$ please see Wikipedia's Deficient number, while for $k \gt 2$, see Abundant number, and the related Highly abundant number.

A list of such numbers is tabulated here.
